# ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Здравствуйте у меня проблема с Phaser . В браузере в консоль мне выдаёт вот такую ошибку - ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined . Вот мой код 
HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    <title>The Game of 2020 Year</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(480, 320, Phaser.AUTO, null, {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
});
var ball;

function preload() {
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
    game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    game.load.image('ball', 'person.png');
}
function create() {
    ball = game.add.sprite(50, 50, 'ball');
}
function update() {}
```

Файл движка и все остальные файлы находятся в одной и той же папке.
Я не понимаю что не так.
Я только недавно начал писать на этом движке и опыта с другими движками не было

Answer (score 0):

Порядок подключения скриптов поменяй местами, т.е сначала фазер, а потом индекс. У тебя начинает выполняться индекс, когда фазер ещё не загружен, и, естественно, отваливает.

Comment: Спасибо помогло . Ещё в теге подключения игры можно прописать defer и всё будет работа без замен : ```<script src="index.js" defer></script>```

Comment: Это.очень.плохая.идея